# open explorer with javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, windows-explorer

Is it possible to open an actual explorer window rather than have the look in directory on your browser? 
So like the windows key + e window... preferably using html or JavaScript?
I've seen it been done in a Firefox add-on called new tab king, but i couldn't figure out how to split up this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most, if not all, javascript is blocked from interacting with anything outside of the browser.
You maybe able to accomplish it with a flash based object. Like they use for some of the copy and paste techniques using javascript.

Its a huge security hole to open up the javascript to the windows environment.
I could ust open a hidden file browser and start coping files, or load something on to your system.

Comment: ok, but could you please tell me the how it works with the add-on "newtabking"?

Answer (score 1):

This is not reliably possible using pure HTML/JavaScript.

In general, website maintainers cannot use JavaScript to force the browser to open an application in a specific way, because that would heavily impact the user experience.

Answer (score 1):

No, not definitely not using HTML and hopefully not in pure JavaScript.

Probably possible using some horrid ActiveX control in Internet Explorer but you ***really*** don't want to go down that route.